# Como faço para pegar dois valores obtidos em uma função através de ponteiros?

Tags: c, funções, ponteiro, alocação, malloc

Estou construindo um programa, cujo o enunciado é fazer com que o usuário forneça 20 números e esses sejam analisados como pares ou impares. No caso, o intuito é criar um vetor A que recebe 20 inteiros e depois criar mais dois vetores contendo os números pares (B) e ímpares (C). Eu pensei em fazer essa questão com alocação dinâmica, mas não consigo pensar em uma forma de pegar esses valores calculados dentro da função (e o enunciado  pede para que seja nela as operações).

Meu código é esse:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int parImpar (int *x);

int main()
{
    int a[5], **par, **impar;
    for (int i =0; i<5; i++){
        scanf ("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    parImpar(a);
    
}

int parImpar (int *x){
    int *B, *C;
    int **par, **impar; 
    int contPar=0 , contImpar=0;
    for (int z = 0; z<5; z++){
        if (x[z]%2 ==0){
            contPar++;
        }
        else{
            contImpar++;
        }
    }
    B = (int*) malloc(contPar*sizeof(int));
    C = (int*) malloc(contImpar*sizeof(int));

    //Tentei fazer usando ponteiro de ponteiros, mas não saiu tbm kkkkk
    **par = &B; 
    **impar = &C;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define TAM 5

int par = 0, impar = 0;

int* pegandoNumerosImpares(int vetorImpar[]){ // int* <--- esse * tá especificando para nossa função que vamos retorna um ponteiro.
   int *vetor_impar;
   
   vetor_impar = calloc(TAM, sizeof(*vetor_impar)); // Sobre o calloc lembrando que quando a função aloca os blocos
                                                    // de memória, ele já vai inicializar eles com 0 cada um.
   if(vetor_impar == NULL){
        printf("Alocação mal sucedida");
   }

    for(int i = 0; i < TAM; i++){
        if(vetorImpar[i] % 2 != 0 ){
            vetor_impar[i] = vetorImpar[i];
            impar++;
        }
    }

    return vetor_impar;
}

int* pegandoNumerosPares(int vetorPar[]){
   int *vetor_par;
   
   vetor_par = calloc(TAM, sizeof(*vetor_par));

   if(vetor_par == NULL){
        printf("Alocação mal sucedida");
   }

    for(int i = 0; i < TAM; i++){
        if(vetorPar[i] % 2 == 0 ){
            vetor_par[i] = vetorPar[i];
            par++;
        }
    }

    return vetor_par;
}

int main(){
    int vetor[TAM], *vetor_par, *vetor_impar, i;

    for(i = 0; i < TAM; i++){
        printf("Preenchar o vetor[%d]: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &vetor[i]);
        __fpurge(stdin);// fflush(stdin); no window.
    }

    vetor_par = pegandoNumerosPares(vetor);
    vetor_impar = pegandoNumerosImpares(vetor);

    printf("\n\n\n");
    printf("-------------\\ Números Pares //-------------\n\n");
    for(i = 0; i < TAM; i++){
        if(*(vetor_par+i) != 0){
            printf("vetor[%d]: %d \n", i, *(vetor_par+i));
        }
    }
    printf("Números de elementos pares: %d", par);

    printf("\n\n\n");
    printf("-------------\\ Números Ímpares //-------------\n\n");
    for(i = 0; i < TAM; i++){
        if(*(vetor_impar+i) != 0){
            printf("vetor[%d]: %d \n", i, *(vetor_impar+i));
        }
    }
    printf("Números de elementos Ímpares: %d", impar);

  return 0;
}
```

Olá Ingrid, seu código apresenta alguns erros:

```
int parImpar (int *x){
```

Não precisa passar um ponteiro como parâmetro para pega um vetor como argumento. É só passar o corpo do vetor como argumento que você vai tá passando o endereço da primeira posição do vetor, já que tanto pela alocação dinâmica ou estática vamos ter uma sequência de blocos adjacentes(um do lado do outro) na memória.

Dê uma olhada nesse [código](https://onlinegdb.com/xHyyp1KRw)!

```
 return vetor_par;
```

Esse retorno de um ponteiro, vai tá passando a primeira posição do bloco de memória alocado. Pois para mudamos a posição do bloco de memória, de um posição para outra posição exemplo:

```
*(vetor+i)
```

Durante a compilação, a expressão `*(vetor+i)` é transformada em `*(vetor + i * sizeof(*vetor))` (Só complatilhando a nível de conhecimento).

Caso tenha dificuldade em Aritmética de ponteiro dê uma olhada nesse [site](https://www.embarcados.com.br/ponteiro-em-c-aritmetica-de-ponteiro/)!

Comment: Olá, Arthur! Mt obrigada pelos esclarecimentos sobre essa questão, gostei mt da forma como vc fez! Mas é pq as vezes me esbarro com esse problema de em uma função ter dois valores, daí eu queria saber como retorná-los para main, sem a necessidade de criar duas delas.

Comment: Bom Ingrid, uma função só retorna um valor por vez. Então aconselho que passe esses valores como referencia, se esses argumentos forem variáveis comuns passe como o operado de endereço & `x(&num)`. Se são  ponteiros só passa o copo deles sem a necessidade do & ex `x(ptr)`. Tem outra possibilidade que seria deixa esses valores como variáveis globais.(Espero ter ajudado.)